# Location based pricing in Softlayer via API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The script in the following link provides location based pricing for each item:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you

When I run above script for example for Toronto location, the returned value does not match the pricing in the SL portal for Toronto. For example, the script returns 8GB @ 0.085/hr vs pricing from portal which is 0.090 for 8GB in Tor:

```
"864": {
"capacity": "8",
"description": "8 GB",
"id": 864,
"itemCategory": {
"categoryCode": "ram",
"id": 3,
"name": "RAM",
"quantityLimit": 0
},
"itemTaxCategoryId": 166,
"keyName": "RAM_8_GB",
"prices": [
{
"currentPriceFlag": "",
"hourlyRecurringFee": ".085",
"id": 112677,
"itemId": 864,
"laborFee": "0",
"locationGroupId": 503,
"onSaleFlag": "",
"oneTimeFee": "0",
"packageReferences": [
{
"id": 891477,
"itemPriceId": 112677,
"packageId": 46
}
],
"quantity": "",
"recurringFee": "56.75",
"setupFee": "0",
"sort": 0
}
],
"softwareDescriptionId": "",
"units": "GB",
"upgradeItemId": ""
},
```

What's wrong with this APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make double check please? because I verified that Portal is displaying the same price than API. I believe the price that you saw was for other datacenter.

1. Select first the datacenter: TOR01 - Toronto
2. Check the price for RAM 8 GB

Comment: Thanks Ruber for your feedback but not following.. Portal shows $0.118 for 8GB in Tor and API returns "hourlyRecurringFee": ".085".  Do you see something different?

Comment: Are you using different accounts to get information from API and Portal?

Comment: Thanks, yes, that was the problem. I was using my ID for api pricing which returns a discoounted pricing.